# How do derivatives within a summation work?

Tags: derivatives, summation

Say I have a function like

$\sum_{h=1}^H v_hz_h + v_0 $

How do I take the derivative of this function with respect to $z_h$?

Comment: if $H<\infty$ then you can differentiate term by term. If $H=\infty$ and the series of derivatives $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z'_h v_h$ converges uniformly then the derivative of the series coincide with the term-wise differentiation of the series